# Audio DSP that can capture and output on the ultrasonic range

Tags: development, embedded-systems, signal-processing

I'm looking for a software programmable DSP embedded platform that is relatively cheap, and can be used for capturing and driving speakers at least on the 60-70 kHz frequency.

Any suggestions?